# What Can I Do If My Test User Cannot Receive My Open Tetsing Invitation

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

I have released  a developed app in open test version in appgallery connect, but some test users give me some feedback that they may fail to receive the invitation link. I want to ask to know how can I make sure about acceptance about open test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask the developer to go to the version page of the application in AppGallery Connect and click on "View details" next to the test users list.

[image]

Here, check the "status" of the invitation of users. If the status column says "Unsent" for a user, please click on "Invite" to send another invitation.

[image]

After clicking on the link in the new invitation email that you receive, you should be able to download the application from the AppGallery.